# Can I say WGS84 is more accurate than NAD83 in terms of their reference ellipsoids?

Tags: coordinate-system

Other than its application, can we say the reason of common adoption of WGS84 is due to its accuracy?

Comment: WGS84 isn't more accurate that NAD83. It just happens to be valid all over the earth, as compared to NAD83, which is valid only in North America.

Comment: Agree with @Devdatta. WGS84 is universal compared to the other one, which is better suited for local applications. NAD83 would be more accurate when compared to WGS84.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Devdatta's answer - that its valid all over the world - there are some other considerations about WGS84:

- Its the "native format" for GPS.
- Its defined in a way that terrain can move underneath it for such things as tectonic movement measurements (of course, that is a disadvantage too, if you were hoping that your terrain does not move over time).
- We've all already agreed to use it for many things (e.g. for ICAO air charts, and as a transform-to-and-from common format). That is related to the reasons above, but now it is a justification in-and-of itself.